# Is it possible for any 2 processes to have the same arrival time in FCFS scheduling in Operating system.

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

Is it possible for any **2 processes** to have the **same arrival time** in **FCFS scheduling** in  Operating system.

Comment: Order in which (same AT processes) are in queue is used to schedule them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a machine with multiple processors, it's possible that two processors make a request at the same time.  However, assuming the queue at the heart FCFS is a single shared data-structure, then all accesses to that queue will be serialized, and the order in which they serialize determines who is ultimately "first."

Think of it like a queue at a bank or a coffee shop.  You could have two different customers walk in at the same time through different doors, but they still have to get in line in sequence.

([Lamport's Bakery Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm) is one example of serialization that you could apply here.)

Comment: I guess, the priority will be used to resolve the issue then.